# Gmail API NodeJS - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Requested entity was not found

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, signature, aliases, gaxios

I'm in trouble with this Gmail API for modifying signature of aliases. I want to modify aliases who have user@domain1, user@domain2 or user@domain3That's work with some users, but not all the users.

I'm at my limit I need help, here is my code and the error:

I have a list of users me wanting to modify, I made the JWT and start my function.

EDIT: This error appear when I try to modify signature, if I delete gmail.users.settings.sendAs.update, this works again. And I can modify signature of primaryEmail.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const keys = require('./credentials.json');
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://mail.google.com',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
];

let list = [
    user1, //working
    user2, //working
    user3, //not working
    user4  //working
];

async function main() {
    const client = new JWT(
        {
            email: keys.client_email,
            key: keys.private_key,
            subject: "admin@domain0",
            scopes: SCOPES,
        }
    );
    const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
    listUsers(client);
}

main();
```

So, I take users list of my admin google account and modify the users in the list.I generate new JWT for each user and change the resource signature with the new signature.

```
/**
 * Lists the first 500 users in the domain.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listUsers(auth) {
    const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth});
    service.users.list({
        customer: 'my_customer',
        maxResults: 500,
        orderBy: 'email',
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
        const users = res.data.users;
        if (users.length) {
            users.filter(utilisateur => list.findIndex(l => l === utilisateur.primaryEmail) !== -1).forEach((user) => {
                //changer signature
                if (user.primaryEmail && user.aliases) {
                    const client = new JWT(
                        {
                            email: keys.client_email,
                            key: keys.private_key,
                            subject: user.primaryEmail,
                            scopes: SCOPES,
                        }
                    );
                    client.subject = user.primaryEmail;
                    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: client});
                    for(let jeton = 0; user.aliases[jeton] && jeton < user.aliases.length; jeton++) {
                        gmail.users.settings.delegates.list({userId:user.primaryEmail});
                        if (user.primaryEmail && user.aliases[jeton] && ((user.aliases[jeton].search("@domain1") !== -1) || (user.aliases[jeton].search("@domain2") !== -1) || (user.aliases[jeton].search("@domain3") !== -1))) {
                            gmail.users.settings.sendAs.update({
                                userId: user.primaryEmail,
                                sendAsEmail: user.aliases[jeton],
                                fields: 'signature',
                                resource: signature
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log('No users found.');
        }
    });
    console.log("Users has been modified");
}

function titleCase(str){
    str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    let final = [ ];
    for(let word of str){
        final.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ word.slice(1));
    }
    return final.join(' ')
}
```

```
(node:5284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Requested entity was not found.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (C:Project_Directory\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:73:27)

at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:Project_Directory\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    (node:5284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing insid
    e of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate
    the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.or
    g/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:5284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
    that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm new with NodeJS, so please be gentle

Comment: You say the users are from different domains? Or do you mean subdomains? Because a service account con only delegate users from the same domain like the service account, if you have different domains, you need to create a separate service account for each domain.

Comment: Sorry, i mean all the users are in the same domain, but I want to modify signatures of users in subdomain (like domain1, domain2, domain3). The subdomain is ours.

For example, that's work with my own mail address, but not for my boss and I don't find any difference in Google account configuration.

Comment: Can you log `user.aliases` to make sure that each alias is a valid value for the respective user?

Comment: When i do user.aliases, I already have valid value, but the problem come from the account, if you have an alias, but you didn't add in Gmail Parameters > Account.